# Admob not show on my app

Tags: android, admob

I have inserted code AdMob ads, but it does not show on my phone (I do not run on the shirt). I have not published app on the store.

In AndroidManifest file

Code in layout file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/gameover"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="7dp"
    android:paddingRight="7dp"
    android:background="@color/bgend" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnBackhome"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/yourBest"
        android:layout_marginBottom="80dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="48dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rate" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnReplay"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btnBackhome"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/yourBest"
        android:layout_marginLeft="34dp"
        android:background="@drawable/play" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/yourBest"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/yourMove"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/yourMove"
        android:layout_marginTop="39dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Best: "
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/yourMove"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/Replay"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="74dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="New: "
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/Best"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Move"
        android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Game Over"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="30sp"

        android:textStyle="bold" />


        <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER" 
        ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-........"
        />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Code gameover.java. I removed the command line to test the virtual machine

```html
package com.vudinh.eastmath;

  

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.app.Activity;

import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;


public class GameOverActivity extends Activity {

 
    
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

  requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
  setContentView(R.layout.game_over);
  // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

  AdView adView = (AdView) this.findViewById(R.id.adView);
        //request TEST ads to avoid being disabled for clicking your own ads
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                //.addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)// This is for emulators
                
               // .addTestDevice("2EAB96D84FE62876379A9C030AA6A0AC") 
                .build();
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);
    
  
 }
    
  
}
```

Proguard file:

```html
-dontwarn **CompatHoneycomb
-keep class android.support.v4.** { *; }
-dontwarn android.support.v4.**
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclassmembers
-optimizationpasses 5
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-dontpreverify
-verbose
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!field/*,!class/merging/*

-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep class com.startapp.** {
*;
}

-keepattributes Exceptions, InnerClasses, Signature, Deprecated, SourceFile,
LineNumberTable, *Annotation*, EnclosingMethod
-dontwarn android.webkit.JavascriptInterface
-dontwarn com.startapp.**

-keep class javax.** { *; }
-keep class org.** { *; }
-keep class twitter4j.** { *; }

-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider
-keep public class * extends android.app.backup.BackupAgentHelper
-keep public class * extends android.preference.Preference
-keep public class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
native <methods>;
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
}

-keepclassmembers enum * {
public static **[] values();
public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

-keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
}
```

Comment: Did you call `adView.show()` somewhere?

Comment: I'm missing it. I can put it just below?   adView.loadAd(adRequest);

Comment: @vudandroid there is no such a method called show() for AdView class. Your code looks fine. Just in case, if you registered AdMob account before August 2014, you should upgrade your AdMob account and get the new adUnitId.

Comment: @SLee: I'm using the new ad ID by Admob

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't appear to be anything wrong with your code.
Have a look at your log, you should see there the ad request and response.
If there are no ads to show, you will see that in the logs, but nothing will be display on the screen.

Comment: Can you help me check the file proguard?

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with it, but it is not implicated in your problem.

Comment: I do not have experience working with logs. you have any solutions to help me?

Comment: Do I need to publish to Google Play the game first and then add the link to AdMob app. Finally my ad will appear? ............... image: http://imgur.com/EZCxrc5

Comment: No. It is not required.

Comment: Hi William ! I see an error......... "Not enough space to show ad! Wants: <480, 90>, Has: <480, 50>"

Comment: So you would not see this error with the code and XML you posted above. So something has changed that you have not told me about. What is it? Suggest you update your code and layout XML.

Comment: Your Adview needs 90dp in height but only has 50dp. Your other elements are consuming too much space. Remove some of the extra large bottom margins you have specified for your other components.

Comment: NB Unless you mark an answer as accepted, no one is ever likely to answer one of your questions again.

Comment: I checked out a hello world application, but it does not display AdMob. When I came horizontal the screen, display banner ads.